# Proper place to put initialization code in JSF?

Tags: jsf

Where is the proper 'place' in JSF to put initialisation snippet that follows, in order to get it executed just one time when the server starts?

```
1.  ExternalContext extContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
2.  HttpSession sesion = (HttpSession)extContext.getSession(true); 
3.  String parA = extContext.getInitParameter("parA");
4.  String parB = someCalculations(parA);       
5.  sesion.setAttribute("parB", parB);
```

Basically I want to read a parameter parA from web.xml context-param section, do some transformations, and include it in session (as new parB parameter).

PostConstructApplicationEvent and eager=true techniques doesn't works because session is null at this point (line 4).
ServletContextListener technique doesn't works because FacesContext isn't available.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you want to execute it once per startup and not for each session? You are setting a session attribute.

Comment: Yes, I want to execute it once per startup. If you forget Session, where can I put new parameter parB? I mean, something like setInitParameter("parB", parB)

Comment: It depends what code should have access to it. If JSF beans then a managed bean seems like a proper choice, probably application scoped.

Comment: Problem solved.

I finally declare my ManagedBean in application scope with eager=true.

Then, in its constructor I set the new parameter this way:

    extContext.getApplicationMap().put("parB", parB);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no sessions at application start time; this requirement is impossible to meet.

I interpret your requirements as:

- perform an expensive application-scope calculation
- inject this application-scope result into other scopes

The JSF way to do this is via managed beans. Here is an application-scope bean to perform the one-time transformation of the context parameter:

```
package foo;

import javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;

@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class SomeCalculationsBean {
  @ManagedProperty("#{initParam.paraA}")
  private String paraA;

  private String someCalculation;

  public String getParaA() {
    return paraA;
  }

  public void setParaA(String paraA) {
    this.paraA = paraA;
    this.someCalculation = //do some transformation
  }

  public String getSomeCalculation() {
    return someCalculation;
  }
}
```

This value can then be injected into other scopes as you need it:

```
package foo;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class SomeSessionBean {
  @ManagedProperty("#{someCalculationsBean.someCalculation}")
  private String paraB;

  public String getParaB() {
    return paraB;
  }

  public void setParaB(String paraB) {
    this.paraB = paraB;
  }
}
```

Code untested. This implementation assumes JSF annotation support but you can do the same thing with `faces-config.xml` bean configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Problem solved. I finally declare my ManagedBean in application scope with eager=true. Then, in its constructor I set the new parameter this way: extContext.getApplicationMap().put("parB", parB);

Comment: In the interests of your unit tests, you might want to avoid using constructors in managed beans and switch to dependency injection instead of using `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()`

Comment: Thanks for the advice, But I dont know how to do that (I am newbie in JSF and Spring). I actually use FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() massively

Comment: I have a blog post discussing testing with `FacesContext` [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2011/12/jsf-mocking-facescontext-for-unit-tests.html) and another about using scope maps [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2012/01/jsf-managed-beans-without-jsf.html). They don't add Spring into the mix and assume knowledge of how the Expression Language resolves variables and places them into scope.